# Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V host running Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

If you install the Hyper-V role on a Windows 2008 R2 Server running Active Directory (on the host), will Microsoft provide support? Is this MS approved or will they say this configuration is not supported and hang up?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/22780/installing-domain-controller-on-hyper-v-host

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's unsupported as much as it is unrecommended. It is a best practice for Hyper V to be installed on a server with no other roles enabled. See the following link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941145%28WS.10%29.aspx

You might also want to check this out:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/3eece08e-09f5-49e2-9403-b67a420af0d2

Answer (score 0):

Works, is supported. If it would not be supported MS would have to block it or provide a warning when you install both roles.

it is not recommended because in LARGER installations you WILL possibly run into performance issues.

I have 2 servers like that, works like a charm.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft always blocks unsupported setups...Hyper V installs on SBS without a warning but that is officially unsupported